# Parameters to program in C with Linux

Tags: c, linux, parameters

How can I send parameters to main in C(Linux):
first one is -c or -d
second is a string like file.

How I'm doing that?

Comment: Read about command line argument.

Comment: `./a.out -c filename` or `./a.out -d filename`

Comment: That's what mains prototype is for - argc, number of parameters, argv, an array of strings, one for each arg.

Comment: please use google before asking questions here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, send data to your program using command line argument Like @haccks said

Second, get the arguments in your code using :

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
```

[Tutorial Here](http://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/argc-and-argv.html)